# how to enable backspace,delete in a asp:TextBox in chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome

My code is like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" CssClass="txtStartDate" runat="server" MaxLength="10"   />&nbsp;
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="startDateRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Dates" ControlToValidate="txtStartDate"
                            EnableClientScript="True" Display="None" Text="*" ErrorMessage="Start date is required."/>
<asp:CompareValidator ForeColor="Red"  id="startDateCompareValidator1" runat="server" Type="Date"
                      ValidationGroup="Dates" Display="None" EnableClientScript="True"
                      Operator="DataTypeCheck" ControlToValidate="txtStartDate" Text="*"
                      ErrorMessage="Start date is not valid or is in an incorrect format. Please use the format yyyy-MM-dd."/>
<asp:RangeValidator id="ReturnDateRangeValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtStartDate" ValidationGroup="Dates"
                    MinimumValue="2005-01-01" MaximumValue="2050-01-01"  Display="None" EnableClientScript="True" Text="*"
                    ErrorMessage="Start date is too far back in time or it is to far in future, please enter a more feasible date."/>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="Calendarextender2" runat="server" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" PopupButtonID="Image2"
                      TargetControlID="txtStartDate" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

I have a date field and I can use delete,backspace into IE but I can't do it into Chrome. My question is how can I enable backspace,delete into Chrome . Any info will be helpful regarding this

Comment: Are they doing nothing (observably) or are you getting different behaviour to what you expected?

Comment: thanks for reply :) they are doing nothing.I mean i'm pressing backspace,delete nothing works in Chrome in that date field but in IE it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use JQuery For this

here is your textbox with event keypress

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" CssClass="txtStartDate"    onkeypress="return allowBackSpace(this);" runat="server" MaxLength="10"   />
```

Some Script

```
function allowBackSpace(val) {
    var keyCodeEntered = (event.which) ? 
    event.which : 
    (window.event.keyCode) ? 
    window.event.keyCode : 
    -1;
    if (keyCodeEntered == 8) {
        $(this).val(""); 
        return false;
    }
    return false;
   }
```